# Portlet - multiple buttons in form

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to write a simple calculator portlet and I have problem with passing value of one of the buttons to my portlet. There's part of my .jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL var = "digit" name = "onDigitPressed">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value = "/html/calc/view.jsp"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= digit %>" method="post" >

<table>
<tr><td>
<aui:button name="button" type = "submit" value="7" id="7"/>  
</td><td>
<aui:button name="button" type = "submit" value="8" id="8" /> </td><td>
<aui:button name="button" type = "submit" value="9" id="9"/> </td><td>
</tr><tr><td>
.
.//more buttons
.
</tr><tr><td>
<aui:button name="button" type = "submit" value="0" id="0" />  </td><td>
<aui:button name="button" type = "submit" value="." id="." />  </td><td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</aui:form>
```

and in `onDigitPressed` method:

```
request.getParameter("button");//returns always null
```

I want to pass value of the button somehow and I want to have only one actionURL to deal with all these buttons. And it would be good to have only one form too. There must be some way, but I have no idea how to do this, I'm new in portlets and JSP.

**EDIT**

My explanation of problem isn't very clear - I want to pass value of **clicked** button. I need that information to know what user wants to compute. Sure I can just spam with `actionURL`s and `form`s, but I want to do this with one form and actionURL.  I bet it has something to do with `onClick` attribute and I'm pretty sure I can't use javascript, because it has to be done on server side and javascript is executed on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, is include an input field or `portlet:param` node that will have a 'digit' specific value

Your problem is that an `aui:button` of type 'submit', is meant to be used as the button that submits a form, so all your buttons will fire the same actionURL. the one stated in the attribute named 'action' of `aui:form`

I can see at least 3 solutions:

1. use another form for each button. This will allow you to set a different `actionURL` for each button, with a unique 'digit' param. This would be a nice idea if your form doesn't feature other params/inputs, and if your forms are created by some iteration like a for loop
2. use one form and one submit button, and include another ui component like a drop down menu, that will provide the 'digit' value
3. Have a hidden input Text that will keep the 'digit' value. Then have each of your  buttons fire a javascript function that will update the 'digit value'

Comment: Second one solves the problem, but looks odd. 
No. 3 - probably using something like Nisha suggested, but doesn't javascript execute in client side? I have to pass it somehow to my portlet. Or do everything in javascript, but I wanted to learn something about portlets (passing parameters etc.). First one looks like the best option, but I want to have the digit buttons like in normal calculator in table 4x3. Unfortunately you can't have form inside table, but you can do opposite - you can put table of content in the form. That's why I can't find good solution of my problem.

Comment: Maybe there is way to have multiple forms in one row. I don't know much about html.

Comment: I've not used solution 3, so I can't provide some code. But the meaning is a) javascript updates the hidden input field, which is contained in the form b) The portlet action on the controller class, will be able to find this value by id or name.

Comment: about solution 1 : why can't you place a form inside a table ? maybe you're trying to put multiple forms inside another form ? I've created buttons wrapped by a aui:form lots of times, contained in data grids, search tables etc

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I messed with using form in place of aui:form and that's why forms didn't in table. D'oh. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using java script.

Javascript code:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1").value;
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2").value;
document.formName.button1 .value = button1 ;
document.formName.button2.value = button2;
document.formName.submit();
```

In JSP:

```
<aui:button type = "submit" value="1" id="button1"/>  
<aui:button type = "submit" value="2" id="button2"/>  
<input type="hidden"  name="button_1" />
<input type="hidden"  name="button_2" />
```

In Java:

```
String button_1= ParamUtil.getString(request, "button_1");
String button_2= ParamUtil.getString(request, "button_2");
```

Comment: you can do this using Liferay resourceURL. This uses the ajax call for sending the data. By this you can send data to action method by every click. For this you have to use servResource() method in your action class.